# mod_rewrite and Apache questions

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, ssl, mod-rewrite

We have an interesting situation in relation to some help desk software that we are trying to setup.  This is a web based software application that allows customers and staff to log into it and access tickets and supply updates, etc.  The challenge we are having deals with the two different domains that we use and the mod_rewrite rules to make it all work with our SSL certificate that is only bound to one of the domains.  I will list the use case scenarios below and the challenges that we are having.

- If you access http://support.domain1.com/support then it redirects fine to https://support.domain2.com/support
- If you access http://support.domain2.com/support then it redirects fine to https://support.domain2.com/support
- If you access https://support.domain1.com/support then it throws an error of "server cannot be found"
- If you access https://support.domain1.com/support/ after having visited https://support.domain2.com/support then you are presented with a "this connection is untrusted" error about the certificate only being valid for the domain2 domain instead of the domain1 domain name

I have tried just about every mod_rewrite rule that I can think of to help make this work and I have not been able to locate the correct combination.  I was curious if anyone had some ideas on how to make the redirects work correctly.  In the end, we are needing all customers and staff to land at https://support.domain2.com/support regardless of the previous URL combinations that they enter, like listed above.

Thanks in advance for your help with this.

Comment: Can we see your existing rewrite rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a certificate for support.domain1.com then no amount of rewrite magic is going to change the errors the users will see when they enter https://support.domain1.com